# Converting a MySQL JSON Encrypted field into a Ruby Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have one field in the authors table (Author Model) for the address, that I store as encrypted and JSON.

I have the following in the migration file:

```
add_column :authors, :address, :json
```

And the following in the Author Model:

```
encrypts :passport_number
```

When I try to retrieve it from the console:

```
author.address
```

I get this:

```
{"address"=>{"city"=>"San Francisco", "state"=>"CA", "street"=>"One Main St", "postal_code"=>"94016"}}
```

If I try to convert it into a hash, as follows:

```
address = JSON.parse(author.address)
```

I get the following error message:

```
.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/json-2.6.2/lib/json/common.rb:216:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of Hash into String (TypeError)
```

Using Rails 7 and MySQL 8.

Any ideas?

Comment: You've got a `Hash`, you don't need to parse it, and it's not JSON. That's Ruby's `inspect` representation for a hash. Maybe you don't need to worry about it at all, Rails seems to have delivered the structure in the form you want. JSON serialization is implicit based on column type in Rails.

Comment: ActiveRecord encrypted attributes can only be stored in VARCHAR or TEXT type columns. With any attribute type other then a string the attribute is first serialized (for example into JSON) and then the resulting string is encrypted on the client side. What you're storing is just a garbled string. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html

Comment: Maybe you're just confusing *encryption* and *encoding* here though? The question doesn't actually make that much sense.

Comment: @tadman I was expecting to do some conversion, but you're right, ActiveRecord gave me the hash.